# WPF program rejects DllImport

Tags: c#, wpf, interop, pinvoke, dllimport

I've a WPF application which runs a scanner (through a C++ com object), creates a (rather large) tiff file and stores it on disk. most of the heavy lifting is done in C++.

The program scans chunks of pages (say 50 - from paperback books) at a time and stores them in the tiff.

Recently, I added some code to bring back a couple of pages from each chunk so I had visual indication that the scan was working OK.

It turns out that this has lead to a massive memory leak.

I'm pretty sure that this is due to not disposing of memory, but where :)?

My immediate problem is that I'm trying to use DeleteObject inside the c# module and it will not compile.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

The compiler is telling me

*A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods*

but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

From the size of the memory leak (20MB ish) I think that the problem is in the c# side, but here's a snippet of the code overall in case I'm missing something.

**C++**

```
STDMETHODIMP CWiaDevice::get_Image(SHORT Index, HBITMAP* pVal)
{
    if (Index >= mStreams.Count())
    {
       return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    if (Index < 0)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    if (mLastBitmap != NULL)
    {
        return E_UNEXPECTED;
    }
    mLastBitmap = Bitmap::FromStream(mStreams[Index]);
    Gdiplus::Status status = mLastBitmap->GetHBITMAP(Color::Black, pVal);
    if (status != Ok)
        return E_FAIL;
    return S_OK;
}


STDMETHODIMP CWiaDevice::ReleaseImage()
{
    if (mLastBitmap != NULL)
    {
        delete mLastBitmap;
        mLastBitmap = NULL;
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

**C#**

```
img = mDevice.Image[0];
SetImage(imgTop, img);
mDevice.ReleaseImage();
```

and

```
private void SetImage(Image img, IntPtr bmp)
{
  var options = BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions();
  img.Source = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bmp, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, options);
  img.InvalidateMeasure();
}
```

I'm planning to put the DeleteObject on bmp in the above method just after a create the img.Source.  I'm presuming that I don't need to explicitly dispose of the img.Source I've previously created and don't see any way of doing it.

Any assistance much appreciated.

Iain

Comment: Methods must be inside classes

Comment: I get that if it's a c# object, but it's an external object.  All the examples I've seen look exactly like this (and are called without a class object)

Comment: No. The methods are always inside a class. The error message tells you this.

Comment: OK.  I've done just that and put the import in a class - that has worked.  Worked in the sense that the function's there and I can call it.  However all the examples I've seen on the web do it the way that I had it in the first place.  Ah well.  Now to see if that's fixed the problem

Comment: No, no examples do it that way because it cannot compile

Answer (score 0):

> A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

The error message is telling you that you can't place a method directly inside a namespace. The method must be inside a class, which you place inside your namespace. This is a static method, so you don't create an instance of the class, but the language rules mean that you still need such a class.